# (SIMPLE) SAS Change export to another path and not replace the document

Tags: excel, sas

I need to change the path to be BR_Historical and instead of it replacing the data I want it to add a row and I cant figure it out

[image: Image of code]

should be a somewhat simple fix but I can't get it to work.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions thank you!

Comment: Add a row to what, the Excel file or SAS data set? And what path changes are required? Why can you you just modify the path in the macro code?

Comment: Please provide way more details on your problem if you need assistance [ask]

Comment: Add a row to the excel file/it populate on the next open row. It is currently replacing old information in the file "BR_output". I changed the path to correct place it should go "BR_Historical" and i removed the replace function. It runs and I dont get errors but it doesnt populate in the excel file

Comment: SAS doesn't provide a simple mechanism for appending to Excel files AFAIK. Neither do Python/R either....can you import the data from excel, add the row and export the new data?